# Unable to update remote database of webservice through rest api

Tags: android, json, rest, bugzilla

I have a bugzilla server which i am trying to access through the rest api . I want to update the database remotely through REST. 
I get the following exception when i try to run my code:

```
W/DB      (  277): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:186)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:265)
W/DB      (  277):  at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:873)
W/DB      (  277):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1020)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
W/DB      (  277):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
W/DB      (  277):  at com.geek.myzilla.RestClient.myputter(RestClient.java:269)
W/DB      (  277):  at com.geek.myzilla.MyZillaActivity.onCreate(MyZillaActivity.java:59)
W/DB      (  277):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
W/DB      (  277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

The RestClient.myputter function looks something like this:

```
public static String myputter(String... params)
{
  String url = params[0];            
  String jsonBody = params[1]; 
  DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut(url);
   try {
     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonBody);
      se.setContentType("text/json");
      se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
      putRequest.setEntity(se);
      putRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      putRequest.setEntity(se);
      putRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
      putRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

      HttpResponse response = client.execute(putRequest);
      int status_code=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

The client.execute line is throwing the exception
Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the Internet permission to the manifest? From [Android developers site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET).

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```